# Angular 2 Observable with setInterval not updating in template using async pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a model class called Task. In it, I get the running time by creating a function that returns an observable...

```
public getRunningTime(): Observable<number> {
    const runningTimeObservable = new Observable<number>(observer => {
        setInterval(() => {
            if (this.isActive) {
                const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                observer.next(currentTime - this.startTime);
            }
            observer.next(this.endTime - this.startTime);
        }, 5000);
    });
    return runningTimeObservable;
}
```

I tie this Task model to a component called TaskListComponent. That component keeps an object containing each task.

```
export class TaskListComponent {

  tasks: object;

  constructor(
    private taskRepositoryService: TaskRepositoryServiceService,
    private taskFactoryService: TaskFactoryService,
    private taskInputDialog: MatDialog) {
    this.tasks = taskRepositoryService.getAllTasks();
  }
```

To which in the template I use ngFor to iterate over.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let task of tasks | keyvalue">
        {{task.value._name}} - {{task.value._color}} <span *ngIf="task.value.startTime">- {{task.value.getRunningTime() | async}}</span>
        <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="removeTask(task.value)">Remove</button>
        <button mat-button (click)="updateTask(task.value)">Update</button>
        <button mat-button (click)="startTask(task)">Start</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to get so that the running time is displayed and updated every 5 seconds using `{{task.value.getRunningTime() | async}}` but it seems to just render nothing on the view.

Any help? I don't think I'm doing this observable right...but I'm not sure how I can create a dynamic value on my Task model...that continuously updates in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're doing it right.

Though you might be getting an exception here `new Date().getTime()`, that angular async pipe swallows. Try `(new Date()).getTime()` to test this assumption.

A bit of advice, if I may:

- use [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) instead of `(new Date()).getTime()`
- use `timer` with `map` instead of Observable constructor -- will be easier. [example](https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/d03c66991792022c97d808445acf2a7b)
- keep createdAt in the model and move Observable to the controller, where you'll recalculate values (if you only care to display the time passed -- then controller is a better place for that)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to perform an asynchronous action according to a timer? Use [RXJS Timer](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/timer) to create an observable that fires at an interval, and then [use flatMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/flatMap) to map that event to your async call that updates your view model. Might look something like this:

```
timer(0, 5000).pipe( flatMap(() => taskRepositoryService.getAllTasks()))
 .subscribe(tasks => this.tasks = tasks);
```